# Changes to RecyclerView led to this Error :E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After implementing all the Recyclerview codes, i still end up with this Error :E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout.

Im not sure if it is because of the layout or where it is placed...

I changed the location of it multiple times and i had to revert back to an older version as some of the solutions i found on the internet caused it to crash.

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    IFirebaseLoadListener {
    private Context context;
    private List<ItemData> itemDataList;
    private List<ItemGroup> dataList;

    AlertDialog dialog;
    IFirebaseLoadListener iFirebaseLoadListener;

    RecyclerView my_recycler_view;

    DatabaseReference myData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        myData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Data");
        dialog = new SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(this).build();
        iFirebaseLoadListener = this;
        //View
        my_recycler_view = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.my_recyclr_view);
        my_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
        my_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        getFirebaseData();

    }

    private void getFirebaseData () {
        dialog.show();
        myData.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange (@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                List<ItemGroup> itemGroups =new ArrayList<>();
                for(DataSnapshot groupSnapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    ItemGroup itemGroup = new ItemGroup();
         itemGroup.setHeaderTitle(groupSnapShot.child("headerTitle").getValue (String.class));
         GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<ItemData>> genericTypeIndicator =new GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<ItemData>>(){};
         itemGroup.setListItem(groupSnapShot.child("listItem").getValue(genericTypeIndicator));
                    itemGroups.add(itemGroup);
                }
                iFirebaseLoadListener.onFirebaseLoadSuccess(itemGroups);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled (@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    iFirebaseLoadListener.onFirebaseLoadFailed(databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFirebaseLoadSuccess(List<ItemGroup> itemGroupList) {
        MyItemGroupAdapter adapter = new 
    MyItemGroupAdapter(this,itemGroupList);
    my_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);

        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFirebaseLoadFailed(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

I have 2 other pages for my Adapters, "MyItemAdapter" and "MyItemGroupAdapter"
but im not sure why it isnt able to call them

My Adapters:

```
public class MyItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyItemAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<ItemData> itemDataList;

    public MyItemAdapter(Context context, List<ItemData> itemDataList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemDataList = itemDataList;
}

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_item,viewGroup,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);

}

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {
        myViewHolder.txt_item_title.setText(itemDataList.get(i).getName());

  Picasso.get().load(itemDataList.get(i).getArt()).into(myViewHolder. img_item);
    myViewHolder.setiItemClickListener(new IItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClickListener(View view, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(context, ""+itemDataList.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


}

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {return (itemDataList != null ? itemDataList.size() : 0);
}

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView txt_item_title;
    ImageView img_item;

        IItemClickListener iItemClickListener;

        public void setiItemClickListener(IItemClickListener iItemClickListener) {
        this.iItemClickListener = iItemClickListener;
    }

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txt_item_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        img_item = itemView.findViewById(R.id.art);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        iItemClickListener.onItemClickListener(view,getAdapterPosition());

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There's no data for your RecyclerView to display when the view is created.

Inside of your `onCreate` you should create your adapter with empty or null data then call `setAdapter()` on your RecyclerView using the empty adapter. Later, you can update the adapter with new data and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter to refresh it.